# BAMT wireless connection no DHCPOFFERS received

Tags: debian, wifi, wpa-supplicant

I have managed to get my Edimax EW-7811Un wireless adapter registered and the correct driver installed, but need it getting connected to my WPA2 PSK network.

```
root@bamt-miner:/home/user# lsusb 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 7392:7811 Edimax Technology Co., Ltd EW-7811Un 802.11n Wi  reless Adapter [Realtek RTL8188CUS]

root@bamt-miner:/home/user# lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
8192cu                542854  0


wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 80:1f:02:7c:6e:3a
          inet6 addr: fe80::821f:2ff:fe7c:6e3a/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:4 errors:0 dropped:885 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2 errors:0 dropped:245 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:198810 (194.1 KiB)  TX bytes:23383 (22.8 KiB)

wlan0:avahi Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 80:1f:02:7c:6e:3a
          inet addr:169.254.5.114  Bcast:169.254.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
```

My /etc/network/interfaces looks like this

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
    wpa-ssid myawesomeinternethotspot
    wpa-psk myunbreakablewpa2password
iface default inet dhcp
```

Is there something that i'm missing?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken you need [wpa-suplicant](https://wiki.debian.org/WiFi/HowToUse#wpa_supplicant).

Comment: wpa-suplicant is already installed. .